# Why is Google App Engine not showing new deployments?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

We have been deploying using `$ gcloud preview app deploy --no-promote --version production` for some time now and everything worked nicely until a couple of days ago.

Not sure what changed, but now our deployments, even though they are executed and `gcloud` gives no errors, are not showing up in the [control panel for Google App Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/).

There's an [issue reported regarding this behavior](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=912&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Stars%20Summary%20log).

Two questions:

1. Why is Google App Engine not showing new deployments?
2. How can I deploy my application again successfully?

Comment: I'm having this problem with version 135. Do I really need to go back to version 112?

Comment: For me this problem disappeared after 2 or 3 versions (I can't remember exactly). After that I have not had this problem again, so I'm guessing in your case it's probably something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to make it available for other people who are currently having problems with this and save you the time of finding out how to fix it.

---

Revert to `gcloud` version 112.0.0 with `$ gcloud components update --version 112.0.0`.

It seems that `gcloud` version 113.0.0 or 114.0.0 has some kind of bug (haven't verified this) that is preventing the deployment to actually be registered and shown in the [control panel for Google App Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/). After going back to version 112.0.0 everything is back to normal. I hope this helps.